# Limit that tends to infinity: $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4^{n}+n!}{1-6^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> I have a question about evaluating this limit:
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4^{n}+n!}{1-6^n}$$

The thing is that I don't know how to continue it.
What I have done so far is:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4^{n}+n!}{1-6^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4^{n}/{n!}+n!/{n!}}{1/{n!}-6^n/{n!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4^{n}/{n!}+1}{0-6^n/{n!}}$$

But I don't know what happens to the $4^{n}$ and $6^n$ in the following limit:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4^{n}/{n!}+1}{0-6^n/{n!}}$$

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation OR http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html

Comment: You shouldn't replace $1/n!$ with $0$. In this case it doesn't hurt much, but it's wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of dividing by $n!$ is good; now you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{4^n}{n!}+1}{\dfrac{1-6^n}{n!}}
$$
Note that replacing $1/n!$ with $0$ is incorrect.

Now $4^n/n!\to0$ and also $(1-6^n)/n!\to0$; since the limit of the numerator is $1>0$ and the denominator is negative (for $n>0$), the limit is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^n}{n!}= \exp(4),$ we must have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^n}{n!} = 0$

Similarly for $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{6^n}{n!}$

Comment: Nice explanation of the convergence to $0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I got why it is $exp(4)$  but why must the limit be $ 0$?

Comment: There is this theorem that states that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is

$$\frac{\frac41\,\frac42\,\frac43\cdots\frac4n+1}{\frac11\,\frac12\,\frac13\cdots\frac1n-\frac61\,\frac62\,\frac63\cdots\frac6n}.$$

Clearly the numerator tends to $1$ and the denominator to $0$. Divergence is to $-\infty$ as the denominator is negative.

---

You can also write $n!>k!k^{n-k}$. Then with $k=7$, $4^n+n!>(4^7+7!)7^{n-7}$ and the numerator grows faster than the denominator $1-6^76^{n-7}$.